# 数値の表記について

Tags: processing

変数

```
int f=0;
```

と置いたとして、

```
2*f
```

と

```
2f
```

の違いを教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2):

```
2 * f
```

これは`2`掛ける変数`f`の値（0）を意味し、実質 2×0 = 0 となります。

```
2f
```

こちらの`f`は Java のリテラル表現で`float`（浮動小数点）を示すトークンです（変数の`f`とは関わりがありません）。
つまり`2`という数値が、`int`（整数）等の他の型の`2`ではなく`float`の`2`であるということです。

[Processing の`float`は Java から継承している](https://processing.org/reference/float.html)ので詳細は Java 関連の情報を当たるといいでしょう。